# Instruções que dependem de variáveis vindas de laço "for", precisam ser executadas em callback?

Tags: javascript

**Por exemplo:**

```
var soma = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
     soma += i;
}

if(soma < 500){
   console.log('Soma é menor que 500');
}
```

**A minha dúvida é:** Já que a condição do `if` depende da variável `b`, que vem do laço for,  o condicional `if` só será executado quando o laço `for` for concluído, ou eu tenho que colocar o `if` em algum tipo de callback?

**Resumindo:** Quero saber se o navegador "pula" o `for` antes de ele terminar, ou se posso confiar que a função/instrução abaixo do `for` só será executada quando ele for concluído.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, podes confiar, para o caso que apresentaste o browser (navegador) não "pula" o for e o if só vai ser executado quando este terminar, simplesmente não entra na tua condição porque a `soma > 500`, `4950` neste caso:

primeiros 5 loops:

> soma(0) += 0
> soma(0) += 1
> soma(1) += 2
> soma(3) += 3
> soma(6) += 4

em que no final destes a nossa soma será `10`, daí que para 100 loops será `4950` e não vai entrar na nossa condição de ser menor que `500`

```js
var soma = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    soma += i;
}

console.log(soma);
if(soma < 500){
   console.log('Soma é menor que 500');
}
```

Aqui tens um exemplo com `200000000` (pode demorar um pouco para acabar de executar):

```js
var soma = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 200000000; i++){
    soma += i;
}
console.log(soma);
```

Mas atenção, se no teu ciclo for estiver a acontecer alguma operação assincrona:

```js
var soma = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  $.get("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8863.json?print=pretty", function( data ) {
    soma += i
  });
}
console.log(soma);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

O browser não vai esperar pelo retorno dessa(s) operação